# Send multiple messages discord python bot in for loop

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I have an array I want to send a handful of messages in a for loop with discord.py. I am trying to use the `on_ready()` command but having a problem with it only sending the first message. I'm fairly new to both async and discord bots. There must be a simpler solution here...

```
client = discord.Client()
links = []
for x in y:
    # do some things
    links.append(stuff)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(12345678910)
    for link in links:
        await channel.send(link)


client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your array looks like?

Comment: They are just a bunch of URL strings.
['google.com', 'amazon.com', 'facebook.com']

Comment: And you want them to be sent to `channel` when the bot is ready?

Comment: Correct, just want to dump them into the channel one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding your code under the `on_ready()` event you could create a loop that runs 1 time once the bot is ready then stops. To create a loop use [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/).

```
from discord.ext.tasks import loop

@loop(count=1)
async def send_links():
    channel = client.get_channel(730064641857683581)
    links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4']
    for link in links:
        await channel.send(link)


@send_links.before_loop
async def before_send_links():
    await client.wait_until_ready()  # Wait until bot is ready.

@send_links.after_loop
async def after_send_links():
    await client.logout()  # Make the bot log out.


send_links.start()
client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: One last question. My program seems to hang after it completes the task. Any way to have it close after executing. client.logout() seems to  be the move but not sure where it goes

Comment: What do you mean by hang?

Comment: The program doesn't terminate after posting the links. I want to run this in cron so don't want a ton of hanging processes.

Comment: You want the bot to post the links then logout?

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much! (A bit embarrassed I couldn't figure that part out :P )

Comment: Update Aug 2021.  `logout` is deprecated, use `Client.close()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

At first, `client = discord.Client()` is absolutely not good for defining `client`. You should define the `client` with

`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='command's prefix here')`. Then if you want to make it a command, you can do this:

```
@client.command()
async def send_link(ctx):
    for link in links:
        await ctx.send(link)
```

But that's not good because it'll send so many messages, so I'd rather to use **embeds**:

```
async def send_link(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    for link in links:
        embed.add_field(name=" ", value=link, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

You shouldn't make it in `on_message` because that's meaningless. And in the code, you did `channel = client.get_channel(1234667890)`. That's also a problem, you have to change it with a real channel id.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Working on some changes. I have the right id in the real code. Part of what I am trying to do is _not_ have a prompt for the messages as I plan to run it in cron

Comment: What does `ctx` represent and also will the `send_link` function be called in `client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)` ?

Comment: You should read some documentation, for example [api references](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). `send_link` is a command that runs when you type `prefix + send_link` in chat, like `.send_link`. Ctx is getting the channel that message sent and sending the messages in that channel. So with these codes, if you define the command_prefix in the `commands.Bot` then type `prefix + send_link` in your guild, it will send the array data.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am trying to have it send without being prompted. I can't seem to find this sort of example in the docs.

Comment: Do you want it to be sent just once?

Comment: Yes, The guy above you answered it, but I do greatly appreciate your time and help.